# Is it correct that $n×(n+1)$ matrix takes $2n^3/3 +n^2/2-7n/6$ flops in the reduction to echelon form?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Source: Linear Algebra and Its Applications David C. Lay

According to the numerical note, for an 2 by 3 matrix the reduction to echelon form can take $2\cdot 2^3/3+2^2/2-7\cdot 2/6 = 5.3+2 -2.3=5$ flops. Let's check if it's true in the following matrix.

$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 5 & 4\\
3 & 7 & -6\\
\end{bmatrix}\space R_2 - R_1 
\qquad 
\approx\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 5 & 4\\
1 & 2 & -10\\
\end{bmatrix} \space R_2 ↔ R_1$
minus: one operation
$ \approx\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -10\\
2 & 5 & 4\\
\end{bmatrix} \space R_2 - 2R_1
\qquad 
\approx\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -10\\
0 & 1 & 24\\
\end{bmatrix} $
minus, multiple of 2: two operations

So in the 2 by 3 matrix, it takes 3 flops , not 5 flops. This is different from the numerical note. Is it correct that $n×(n+1)$ matrix takes $2n^3/3 +n^2/2-7n/6$ flops in the reduction to echelon form? If so, why it's different in my example?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's true, because a flop is one arithmetic operation on *two floating point numbers,* not one arithmetic operation on the whole row. Consider:

$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 & 4\\
3 & 4 & 5\\
\end{bmatrix} R_2 - 3 R_1/2 
\approx\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 & 4\\
0 & -1/2 & -1\\
\end{bmatrix}$

This takes five flops, one to calculate $3/2$, and two each to subtract $3/2$ times the first row from the second row. (You don't need to do any arithmetic operations with the first element of the second row, because you know it must be $0$ in echelon form.)

Furthermore, five flops would be the maximum it can take; it's always possible to reduce a matrix to echelon form in zero flops, if it's already in echelon form!

Comment: Then there are also two operations to calculate $3-2*(3/2)$, so the total operation is one+two+two+two= 7 operations.

Comment: The reason you subtract $3/2$ times the first row from the second row is because $3$ and $2$ are the first numbers of those two rows. We select those numbers so that $3/2$ times the first number of the first row ($2$) subtracted from the first number of the second row ($3$) is $0$, which puts it in row echelon form. So, you don't have to actually do the subtraction, because the numbers we select it automatically make it zero. Unfortunately, I don't know any relevant books. This thread is getting long; if you don't have any other questions, I think we should delete all these comments now...

Comment: Actually you made the first entry of the second row $0$ by subtracing with the selected numbers as you mentioned in "We select those numbers so that $3/2$ times the first number of the first row ($2$) subtracted from the first number of the second row ($3$) is $0$, which puts it in row echelon form."

Comment: Yes, it makes it $0$, but we *don't have to actually do the subtraction*. We selected the numbers so that we *know* it's going to be $0$, which means instead of actually doing the subtraction, we can just say it's $0$.

Comment: How can we say 3 and 2 are just 0s?